# Karate Runner -> karate jar : Command line args settings issue

Tags: jar, command, line, karate, args

I am using Visual Studio code and Karate Runner plugin is installed. Using karate-config.js with  standalone jar (karate.jar). I have tried to configure in karate runner settings in VS code for Karate Runner -> karate jar : Command line args as "java -Dkarate.config.dir=test/resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main" but it throws an exception like

Executing task: java -Dkarate.config.dir=test/resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main "d:\GitHub\KarateTestFramework\test\features\script\all_users.feature:9" <

Error: Could not find or load main class .config.dir=test.resources.
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command java -Dkarate.config.dir=test/resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main "d:\GitHub\KarateTestFramework\test\features\script\all_users.feature:9"" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Also, I have tried full path for -Dkarate.config.dir=D:/GitHub/KarateTestFramework/test/resources but didn't work either.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ChandramohanRamabadran, I tried to replicate the issue on my system. I believe it's not a bug!

It's happening because your VisualStudio is using PowerShell instead of CMD. I believe you might have missed the step to [change the default shell of VisualStudio after installing Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#change-default-shell). Try [updating the default shell from PowerShell to CMD](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#change-default-shell); then you should be good.

However, if you still want to use PowerShell, then update the command

```
java -Dkarate.config.dir=test/resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main
```

to

```
java `-Dkarate.config.dir`=test/resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main
```

**More context over the issue:**
PowerShell has a more standard rule to parse system-properties parameters which are different from CMD. In a PowerShell command, the parameter names always begin with a hyphen. The hyphen tells PowerShell that the item in the command is a parameter name.

Here, we are passing the parameter as `-Dkarate.config.dir`, PowerShell sights the parameter name-tag as `-Dkarate` and not `-Dkarate.config.dir`; hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Thanks for reporting it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1330

For now please find a workaround. Karate will look for `karate-config.js` in the current directory or the classpath. So if you change the command to something like this (please try variations) it should work

```
-cp 'karate.jar;test/resources/'
```

Comment: I have tried the above command and different variations but didn't work. Please update me once this bug has been addressed.

Comment: @ChandramohanRamabadran I suggest you spend some time helping us fix this, this is an open source project

Comment: I have changed preferred terminal shell from Powershell to command as default for VS code and followed the below listed steps

1) Press Ctrl + Shift + P to show all commands.
2) Type shell in the displayed text box to filter the list.
3) Select Terminal: Select Default Shell .
4) You will be prompted to Select your preferred terminal shell, you can change this later in your settings or follow the same process as we do now.
I have changed the karate runner->karate jar:Command Line Args settings as java -Dkarate.config.dir=resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main

Answer (score 1):

I have changed preferred terminal shell from Powershell to command as default for VS code and followed the below listed steps

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + P to show all commands.
2. Type shell in the displayed text box to filter the list.
3. Select Terminal: Select Default Shell .
4. You will be prompted to Select your preferred terminal shell, you can change this later in your settings or follow the same process as we do now.

I have changed the karate runner->karate jar:Command Line Args settings as java -Dkarate.config.dir=resources/ -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main

Now its working fine.